# Compounded multiplier and divider in Python

Tags: python, math

If I recursively divide `3,200` by `2` fourteen times I get `0.1953125`

```
(((((((((((((3200/2)/2)/2)/2)/2)/2)/2)/2)/2)/2)/2)/2)/2)/2 = 0.1953125
```

If I recursively times `0.1953125` by `2` fourteen time I get `3,200`

```
(((((((((((((0.1953125*2)*2)*2)*2)*2)*2)*2)*2)*2)*2)*2)*2)*2)*2 = 3,200
```

I am trying find the term for the mathematical function that does this and how to implement it in Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> 3200.0 / 2**14
0.1953125
>>> 
>>> 0.1953125 * 2**14
3200.0
```

`**` means *power* in Python, just like in Fortran.

Note that (if you're using the number 2 exclusively) you can obtain 2<sup>x</sup> with a bitwise shift as well:

```
>>> 3200.0 / (1 << 14)
0.1953125
>>> 
>>> 0.1953125 * (1 << 14)
3200.0
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the power function: 3200/(2^14) = 0.1953125 and 0.1953125* (2^14) is 3200

Answer (score 1):

Your first equation is equal to

```
3200/(2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2)
```

since multiplication is [associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) (i.e., parens don't matter)

Similarly (and even more easily) your second equation is

```
0.1953125*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2
```

In both cases, the strings of `2*2*...` are 2 to the power of 14, which, in python is `2**14` or [`math.pow(2,14)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#power-and-logarithmic-functions).

So we can rewrite them as

```
3200 / (2**14)
```

[which is the same as `3200 * 2**(-14)`, since negative powers are the reciprocals of positive powers] and

```
0.1953125 * 2**14
```